# Folium GeoJson animated map - minimum speed does not set correctly

Tags: python, geojson, folium

I'm using Folium and the TimestampedGeoJson plugin to animate some markers moving across the map.

The problem is that the animation always starts off playing at 1fps, whereas i have set my min_speed to 20. The time slider works properly in that if i adjust it then the animation will start playing at the indicated speed, but initially it will show 20 fps (the minimum) but always start of playing at 1 fps until it is adjusted.

How can i make it start playing at the correct speed?

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import folium
from folium.plugins import TimestampedGeoJson
from folium import FeatureGroup, plugins
from datetime import datetime
import pickle  

def sort_output_table(output, location_df):
    df_in = output[['Location', 'Time_in',]].copy()
    df_in.rename(columns={'Time_in':'Time'}, inplace=True)
    df_out = output[['Location', 'Time_out',]].copy()
    df_out.rename(columns={'Time_out':'Time'}, inplace=True)

    df = pd.concat([df_in, df_out], axis =0).sort_values(by='Time', ascending=True)
    df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    merged_df = df.merge(location_df[['Location', 'Latitude', 'Longitude']], on='Location', how='left')
    df['Latitude'] = merged_df['Latitude']
    df['Longitude'] = merged_df['Longitude']
    return(df)

def move_marker(current_time, df):
    # Find the segment that contains the current time
    for i, row in df[:-1].iterrows():
        if row['Time'] <= current_time <= df.iloc[i + 1]['Time']:
            point_before, point_after = row, df.iloc[i + 1]
            break
    else:
        return None

    # Interpolate between the two points based on time
    time_before = point_before['Time']
    time_after = point_after['Time']    
    time_delta = (current_time - time_before) / (time_after - time_before)    
    lat = point_before['Latitude'] + (point_after['Latitude'] - point_before['Latitude']) * time_delta
    lng = point_before['Longitude'] + (point_after['Longitude'] - point_before['Longitude']) * time_delta

    return lng, lat

# Define function to create the feature collection
def create_feature_collection(df, time_step):
    features = []

    # create moving marker features
    moving_points = []
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if i < len(df) - 1:
            next_row = df.iloc[i + 1]
            time_delta = (next_row['Time'] - row['Time']).total_seconds()
            num_points = int(time_delta / time_step)

            for j in range(num_points + 1):  # Include endpoint by adding 1
                time = row['Time'] + pd.Timedelta(seconds=time_step * j)
                moving_coords = move_marker(time, df)
                if moving_coords:
                    moving_points.append({
                        'coordinates': moving_coords,
                        'time': time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
                    })
    # icon_path = r'https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/75/PNG/128/ship_14716.png'
    icon = folium.Icon(color="red",icon="fa-truck", prefix='fa')

    moving_feature = {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'MultiPoint',
            'coordinates': [point['coordinates'] for point in moving_points]
        },
        'properties': {
            'times': [point['time'] for point in moving_points],
            'icon': "marker",
            'iconstyle': {
                'iconUrl': r'https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/75/PNG/128/ship_14716.png',
                'iconSize': [30, 30],
                'iconAnchor': [15, 15],
                'popupAnchor': [0, -15],
                'iconRotate': 45,            
            }
        }
    }

    features.append(moving_feature)

    feature_collection = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": features}
    return feature_collection

def main(location_df, output_table):
    
    # Create the map
    m = folium.Map(location=[location_df['Latitude'].mean(), location_df['Longitude'].mean()], zoom_start=10)
        
    folium.TileLayer('stamenwatercolor').add_to(m)
    folium.TileLayer('cartodbpositron').add_to(m)
    folium.TileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.bzh/br/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', name = "OSM", attr = '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Tiles courtesy of <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.bzh/" target="_blank">Breton OpenStreetMap Team</a>').add_to(m)
    folium.TileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Ocean/World_Ocean_Base/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', name = "Ocean", attr = 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Sources: GEBCO, NOAA, CHS, OSU, UNH, CSUMB, National Geographic, DeLorme, NAVTEQ, and Esri').add_to(m)

    # Create the feature group and add it to the map
    fg = FeatureGroup(name="Marker Locations")

    # Create the feature collection for both markers
    feature_collections = []
    for i in range(len(output_table)):
        df = sort_output_table(output_table[i], location_df)
        feature_collection = create_feature_collection(df, 30)  # time_step = N seconds
        feature_collections.append(feature_collection)

    # Merge feature collections
    merged_feature_collection = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [f for fc in feature_collections for f in fc["features"]]
    }

    # Create the TimestampedGeoJson layer with custom styling
    timestamped_geojson = TimestampedGeoJson(
        data=merged_feature_collection,
        period="PT30S",
        duration="PT30S",  # needs to match feature collection seconds
        auto_play=True,
        loop=True,
        speed_slider=True,
        min_speed=20,
        max_speed=100,
        time_slider_drag_update=True,
        add_last_point=True,
        loop_button=True,
        date_options="HH:mm:ss",
        transition_time=0,
    )

    # Add the TimestampedGeoJson layer to the map
    m.add_child(timestamped_geojson)
    
    m.add_child(fg)
    # Add markers for each location
    for i, row in location_df.iterrows():
        if row.Location == 0:
            folium.Marker(
                location=[row["Latitude"], row["Longitude"]],
                popup=row["Name"],
                icon=folium.features.CustomIcon(
                    r"https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/2836/PNG/512/port_ship_icon_180129.png",
                    icon_size=(20, 20),
                    icon_anchor=(10, 14)
                )
            ).add_to(m)
        else:
            folium.Marker(
                location=[row["Latitude"], row["Longitude"]],
                popup=row["Name"],
                icon=folium.features.CustomIcon(
                    r"https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1623/PNG/512/3737615-electric-power-offshore-turbine-wind_108914.png",
                    icon_size=(20, 20),
                    icon_anchor=(10, 14)
                )
            ).add_to(m)
    # Add a layer control to the map
    folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

    # add a mini map
    minimap = plugins.MiniMap()
    m.add_child(minimap)
    
    # Save the map as an HTML file
    
    html_string = m.get_root().render()
    file_name = 'map3.html'

    with open(file_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(html_string)    
    
    return (html_string)
```

I am wondering if there is either some initial setting i am missing, or if not whether there is some way i can touch the slider to make it change?

Thank you.